# Adding Validation to Input Field to Not Allow Duplicate Entries

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, unique

Right now, I have a dialog box that pops up when an Add button is clicked. Whenever the submit button is pressed inside the dialog box, it inserts it into a database. There are 2 fields, MR_ID and Supp_ID. Supp_ID accepts integers only. I want to also add more validation to Supp_ID so that it will not submit or insert if the value entered is a duplicate value and already in the database. How can I do this?

JavaScript:

```
$( function() {


    $("#insertButton").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });   

    var dialog, form,

      mr_id_dialog = $( "#mr_id_dialog" ),
      supplier_id = $( "#supplier_id" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_id_dialog ).add( supplier_id ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

   function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( supplier_id, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid Supplier ID" );
      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#index_table tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val()+"-"+supplier_id );
          var type = $(this).attr('id');
          var value = $(this).val();
          console.log(type + " : " + value);
          // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
          switch (type) {
            case "mr_id_dialog":
                dict["MR_ID"] = parseInt(value);
                console.log(dict['MR_ID']);
              break;
            case "supplier_id":
                dict["Supp_ID"] = value;
              break;
            }
        });
        $( "#index_table tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        console.log(dict);

        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row inserted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to insert");
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });


      }
      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Supplier ID": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( "#insertButton" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog({
          position: ['center', 'top'],
          show: 'blind',
          hide: 'blind'
      });
      dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Code for my dialog box:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Supplier ID">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<!-- Dialog box displayed after add row button is clicked -->
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_id">MR_ID</label>
      <select name="mr_id" id="mr_id_dialog" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="300">
          <?php foreach($user1->fetchAll() as $user2) { ?>
            <option>
                <?php echo $user2['MR_ID'];?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select><br><br>
      <label for="supplier_id">Supplier ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="supp_id" id="supplier_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" value="99">

      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send ajax call to the server as soon as user leaves that field and check in the database whether any record exist with the same value.

if yes then you can throw error message to the user to use different value.

Comment: I figured AJAX might be the way to go, but how would this code look?

Comment: I am attaching below example code which might be useful for you,                          <script>function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "xmlhttp_info.txt?selectedvalue="+selectedfieldvalue, true);
  xhttp.send();
}</script> you need to pass the selectedfieldvalue to the server and write some backend logic whcih checks for the database record with the same value .

Comment: im not sure how i would use this, seems a bit confusing to me

Comment: you can attach onblur event to the supplier ID input field and then call above method.